# SHOWING Build failed with an exception. while compiling flutter project. Error message is given below

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':webview_flutter_android'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\PNT.gradle\caches\jars-9\0242115a4d091d8434bcca2f35546e78\proj.jar.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':webview_flutter_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':webview_flutter_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.